# Fill contour of a cylinder when using Tikz arcs

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a cylinder using Tikz to make it look like a solid bar, I'm defining to arcs and filling the contour generated by this two circumference but when I'm trying to do the filling it draws the arcs and make a rectangle instead of curve this contour. My current code is:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-30:1cm)}, y={(90:1cm)}, z={(210:1cm)}]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radio}{0.5}
        \draw[blue, ultra thick, fill=blue] (\radio,0,0) arc (0:180:\radio) -- ++ (0,0,8) arc(180:0:\radio) -- cycle ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

An the result with some skeleton to see what's happenning is this:
[image]

Hope somebody could help me :(

Comment: You can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494894/how-to-correctly-fill-3d-figures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arc angles are based on screen coordinates, not the z=0 plane coordinates.  After some tests I noticed that the z lines were perfectly symmetrical about 135 degrees.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-30:1cm)}, y={(90:1cm)}, z={(210:1cm)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\radio}{0.5}
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, fill=blue] (\radio,0,0) arc (-45:135:\radio) -- ++ (0,0,8) arc(135:-45:\radio) -- cycle ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!