# Have sides of translucent cylinder appear

Tags: 3d, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

This is a very simple answer probably, but I want/need the sides of this cylinder to appear. The goal is to have it be for volumes of rotation by cylindrical shells.

The goal is to have something like the green cylinder here, but with somewhat see-through sides
[image]

Right now, I have this:
[image]

Ideally, simplest code fixes are better since then I could adjust it and learn from it. (No thickness is needed)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={30}{20}, declare function={h=1;r=2;}]

  \draw[fill=blue!25,fill opacity=0.5] 
  (r,0,0) 
  -- plot[variable=\x,domain=360:0,smooth] ({r*cos(\x)},{r*sin(\x)},0)
  -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth] ({r*cos(\x)},{r*sin(\x)},h);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need to plot this and use 3d? You could maybe simply draw two ellipses and add the front part of the cylinder like this: `\tikz{ \draw[fill=blue!25, fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=2, y radius=1]; \draw[fill=blue!25, fill opacity=0.5] (0,-1) ellipse[x radius=2, y radius=1]; \draw[fill=blue!25, fill opacity=0.5] (2,0) arc[start angle=360, end angle=180, x radius=2, y radius=1] -- +(0,-1) arc[start angle=180, end angle=360, x radius=2, y radius=1] -- cycle; }`

Comment: I do want the 3d because I'll be rotating it around axes. In a way, think of this as the basis of snapshots of a video of a rotating hollow cylinder.

Comment: In that case, you really want a 3D-aware tool, which PGF/TikZ isn't. For example, you have to draw things in the right order (or layer them) because the code has no notion of depth. In this, it is quite unlike tools designed for 3D from the ground up.

Comment: I was trying to follow this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494896/261119 so it does seem possible to use it with Tikz, though it might not be the best method.

Comment: Asymptote, on the other hand, is 3D aware. See the [gallery](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dgraphs/) specific the one near the bottom called "washer method".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
axis equal,
axis lines=none,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat, blue,
opacity=0.5,
domain=0:360, samples=100,
domain y=0:1, samples y=2,
] ({2*cos(x)},{2*sin(x)},y);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A blue transparent ring]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\azimuth}{25}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\elevation}{30}
\begin{axis}[
view={\azimuth}{\elevation},
colormap={mycolor}{color=(blue)color=(blue)},
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
axis equal,
axis lines=none,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
domain=\azimuth:180+\azimuth, samples=100,
domain y=0:1, samples y=2,
] ({2*cos(x)},{2*sin(x)},y);
\addplot3[
surf, shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
domain=0:360, samples=100,
domain y=0:1, samples y=2,
] ({1.8*cos(x)},{1.8*sin(x)},y);
\addplot3[
surf, shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
domain=-180+\azimuth:\azimuth, samples=100,
domain y=0:1, samples y=2,
] ({2*cos(x)},{2*sin(x)},y);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two blue transparent rings inside each other]